# Conference Speakers

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If a speaker for ROS were invited to a conference in US or Europe, would someone be able to give a presentation ?

Would the speaker be able to get themselves somewhere or would travel need to be provided ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126411/conference-speakers/) by [uaflyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/10681/uaflyer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2014-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To me it seems that this depends highly on the combination of: Who is the speaker + What conference + What funding is available. I personally have been on a conference as an invited speaker within our research area (i.e. not ROS itself) on our own funds, so it is not impossible in general.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0